# Unable to understand logic in insertion in binary search tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I was studying binary search tree and I came through this code which I am unable to understand

//head is the root node &num is the key element

```
void generate(struct node **head, int num)
{
    struct node *temp = *head, *prev = *head;
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        (*head)->a = num;
        (*head)->left = (*head)->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (num > temp->a)
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->right;
            }
            else
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->left;
            }
        }
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->a = num;
```

//I am not able to understand the following lines

```
        if (num >= prev->a)
        {
            prev->right = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->left = temp;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In binary search tree the left child has a lower value that the parent, and the right child has a higher value that the parent. Then, if you want to insert a new node, you have to find his site. While the value of the nodes of the tree is less than your **num**, you navigate the tree to the right. When the value of one node is highter than your num, you navigate the tree to the left, not to the right. This is the loop until you reach a NULL node, that will be the place of your new node with value **num**.

Answer (score 0):

In this code block.

prev pointer will point to the leaf node after traversing whole tree based upon the value of **num**.

**temp** is NULL, so space has been allocated using malloc so that it can hold a node with value as **num**.

Now, if value of num is greater than value of its parent i.e. prev->a, **temp** will become right child of prev.

If value of num is greater than value of its parent i.e prev-a, **temp** will become left child of prev.

Answer (score 0):

Just above the code you don't understand, the program is going down the tree going left or right. When `num` is smaller than the value stored at node `temp`, the exploration continues on the left branch, otherwise it continues on the right branch. During this process, it keeps track of `prev` which is the parent node of `temp`.

The search ends, when `temp` is null. This means that there is no node attached to the left or right branch where we wanted to go. This is where `num` has to be inserted.

It then creates a new node called `temp`, stores the `num` in it. 
Note that there is a small error here. One shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc`. This malloc works, but it is considered bad practice.

Then it retest if the node must be attached as a left or right branch of the parent node `prev` and attach it accordingly. This is what the code you don't understand does.

There is a bad bug in this code because the new node has undefined values for left and right branches.

```
temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->a = num;
temp->right = temp->left = NULL;  // <-- missing instruction
```